# how to generate API token for jenkins from Docker

Tags: docker

I created jenkins server from a docker container and trying to setup my jenkins api tokens from a dockerfile so that I don't have to regenerate from whenever I restart or recreate the container. Not sure hoe this can be done. Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched this a lot time. Finally I find a way to do this programmatically But NOT in dockerfile.

1. you should set user and password in dockerfile.
   https://www.popularowl.com/jenkins/automating-jenkins-install-docker-terraform/
2. get crumb and cookie using this api
   curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json --user admin:admin
3. generate token using the follow api
   curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/user/admin/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' 
   -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID.1a27c20d=node02jg4glfuhga8aijcxtxezlyf15.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly' 
   -H 'Jenkins-Crumb: 12f10c096677087e5f97170c8f0b8e52cb83ce49cb5e996ac13a8bc88dcbb254' 
   --data 'newTokenName=foo' 
   --user admin:admin

Hope this can help you